# Is Taylor's series for cos uniformly convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

Is it true that Taylor's series for cos uniformly convergent (for all $\mathbb{R}$)?

Comment: No, the series is kind of useless if $x=100$, we need lots of terms for decent accuracy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The series converges pointwise on $\mathbb{R}$ and uniformly on any finite closed interval $[a,b]$, but not uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$. Why? Observe that $\cos$ is a bounded function, but the partial sums of its Taylor series, being polynomials, are unbounded.